# Why is the scroll bar lagging in safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a centered website with a set width.

Here is the current CSS for the content:

```
.page-content {
    max-width: 1022px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Originally the max width was 1200px but then I changed it to 1022px. After I changed the width of my website the scrollbar began to lag ONLY in safari. But when I change the max-width back to 1200px it works normally. The content itself does not lag but the scrollbar lags. It takes a second for the scrollbar to catch up with the new scroll position. Has anyone else experienced this issue? What should I do? This seems to be purely a CSS and HTML issue.

Answer (score 0):

thats sounds like safari bug, because as you said.. it's working great in every other browser.

Comment: Yea I think that's what it is. Should I just ignore it and continue developing my website? Do bugs usually get fixed? I want my website to work across all browsers.

Comment: i think you should report this bug if you can, and anyway, you cant really do anything  about that (at least that i know of)

Comment: Yea I know. I can't report it right now. And I feel like it might take a while for them to fix the bug. I don't think there is another way to center a website either. This sucks.